# Why do I get different results when training a Keras model when I multiply the loss by a scalar?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'd present my model, but I've seen this result across the board. As en example, I'm training a model now where with use straight mse, the loss bottomed out at 0.0160. But when I used 100 * mse, the loss is now shooting down below 0.2, where I would have expected it to bottom out around 1.6. Does anybody have any idea why training Keras models might be sensitive to multiplying losses by scalars?

EDIT: And just to clarify, when this has happened to me, the model does end up doing better so it's not just a numerical quirk.

EDIT2: I've been asked to provide some example code, so I will. I'm working with using a convolutional variational autoencoder as a generative model. Here is my custom loss function:

```
def vae_loss (input_image, decoder_output):
    mse_loss = mse(input_image, decoder_output)
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * (K.mean(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=[-1,-2,-3]))
    return mse_loss         # (A)
    #return 100 * mse_loss  # (B)
```

I realize that this doesn't use `kl_loss`, this is just meant as an experiment. I'm compiling the model with:

```
vae.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=vae_loss)
```

and fitting with:

```
vae.fit_generator(random_crop(data[:500,:,:,:], 128, 128),
              validation_data=random_crop(data[500:,:,:,:], 128, 128),
              shuffle=True, steps_per_epoch=64, epochs=5, validation_steps=50)
```

Using `A` as the loss function converges to  a loss of 0.0160. If using `B` caused the model to converge to the identical solution (and I would expect it to since multiplying by a scalar doesn't change the location of local minima), I would expect it to converge to a loss of 1.60, 100 times `A`. But it doesn't. In fact, `B` does significantly better than `A` both in terms of loss and in terms of the qualitative products of the network.

Comment: Could you please add little more details, like verbose while training?

Comment: This isn't a question about a particular project (although I am seeing it in my current work) and is more a question in general. Could it have something to do with the fact that multiplying the loss by a scalar also multiplies the gradient?

Comment: It would be better if you add sample of your code. At least training and multiplying portion.

Comment: I understand, @Mufeed, I've included the relevant code snippets.

Comment: @DroidGadgets I've included the relevant code snippets.

Comment: How exactly are you making these experiments? It could just be differences due to random initialization or shuffling of the dataset (as you set shuffle to True).

Comment: Just a idea from me (not enough for an answer): I think it's due to the optimizer. Your bigger loss function might impact the starting learning rate.

Comment: How does your training decide when it has converged?  Is that criterion properly adjusted for the scalar?

Comment: Is `vae_loss()` the final loss of your model? Do you have any L1, L2 regularizations?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with the way Keras decides the network has converged - it probably compares the difference between loss functions to a fixed number, for example 0.01. If it can't improve by 0.01 it stops.

If you multiple the loss by 100, Keras still uses 0.01 for testing convergence - so it performs more iterations and optimizes better.

Comment: Keras doesn't "decide" when the network has converged, that's the users' job.

Comment: This is only true if you use the Callback Early stopping, which isn't the case in this question.